# ORDER BY RAND not working

Tags: php, mysql, database

hope all good. i have a problem with some php that is not randomly selecting an ip. I will try to explain.

```
<select name="State">
<option value="0" selected="selected">Select a State</option>
<option value="AL">Alabama</option>
<option value="AK">Alaska</option>
<option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
<option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
   etc.....
</select>
```

Any-time the customer selects a a state and submits the form it goes to my database and pulls an ip address releavant to the state. This is what my database looks like

```
+-------+---------------+
| state |      ip       |
+-------+---------------+
| AL    | 67.100.244.74 |
| AK    | 68.20.131.135 |
| AZ    | 64.134.225.33 |
+-------+---------------+
```

Thanks to people on this forum i have some php code that is collecting the ip address when the form is submitted and it gets sent to my email. Perfect. here is the code

```
<?php
// visit http://php.net/pdo for more details
// start error handling

try 
{
  // connect
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=name', 'dbuser', 'pass');
  // enable error handling through exceptions
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  // create safe query
  $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT ip FROM vincer WHERE state = ? ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
  // pass data & execute query (since the data are of string type
  // and therefore can be passed in this lazy way)
  $query->execute(array($_POST['State']));
  // get value
  $ip = $query->fetchColumn();
  // print out the IP address using $ip
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
  echo "sorry, there was an error.";
  mail("email@gmail.com", "database error", $e->getMessage(), "From: email@gmail.com");
}
?><?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "1stoptutorials@gmail.com";
    $email_subject = "This is a test";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['State']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $state = $_POST['State']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "State: ".clean_string($ip)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
if (!mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers))
{
    echo "failed to send message";
}  

?>
```

The only thing it is not doing is grabbing a random ip from the state. For each state ie AL,AK,AZ etc.. i have about 150 different ip addresses. So lets say someone selects the state of Alabama (AL), i want it to randomly choose and ip from the database that is in the same row as AL. It is picking up the ip address ok, but it is always sending me the same ip for AL.

According to the code it should be doing this because the ORDER BY RAND is in there

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT ip FROM vincer WHERE state = ? ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
```

I asked around and some people suggested i need another column in my table with a name of id, so this is what it should look like

```
-------+-------+---------------+
| id   | state |      ip       |
+------+-------+---------------+
|  1   | AL    | 67.100.244.74 |
|  2   | AK    | 68.20.131.135 |
|  3   | AZ    | 64.134.225.33 |
+------+-------+---------------+
```

They say i need the id so i can randomly pull in the ip. Does anyone know what php code i need to add this id to make this all work. Any help would be much appreciated

Thanks Everyone

Ali

Comment: If you have only one record for a state, it will always pull **that** record.  Also note that RAND() will run the same random sequence every time, so you're getting the same data as long as the table does not change.

Comment: If you have only one row with `state='AL'`, it's no wonder that you get the same ip all the time.

Comment: "Also note that RAND() will run the same random sequence every time, so you're getting the same data as long as the table does not change"
where do you have this from @John ?

If i use "order by rand() LIMIT 1" on a table, i always get a different result, even if the table does not change.

user1010914 
what does "select rand()" give you if you execute it multiple times? maybe the mysql configuration does not use a proper seed source.

Comment: Thanks Flyingmana for your answer. To be honest that is what is happening, it keeps grabbing the same table row and displaying the same ip. How do i make it change the table row then? Any help would be great

Comment: Your SQL looks right, so something inobvious is wrong.  Please cut down your code sample to the shortest, self-contained sample that demonstrates the problem.  (Essentially, just the PDO query followed by a print.  A small table with just a few records would help, too.)  For example, is the `try{}` block blowing up and some old value of `$ip` being re-used?  We don't know and can't easily tell.

Answer (score 3):

`RAND()` will give different values every time.
If you don't want this you can give a **fixed** seed value.
If you're paranoid, you can supply a different seed value every time.

```
SELECT ip FROM vincer WHERE state = ? ORDER BY RAND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())) LIMIT 1
```

If there's are very few different ip's in a state the chances of seeing the same ip go up as number of ip's approaches one.
If there's only 1 then **that** will be returned of course.

You can see the `RAND()` that's used by changing the query to:

```
SELECT @rand:= RAND() as rand, ip 
FROM vincer 
WHERE state = ? 
ORDER BY rand 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your message and help. I do want different values every time. I tryed out your code above and it still will not bring me in different ip address everytime. For each state i have about 150 different ip rows, example AL,67.100.244.74, AL,67.900.114.72, AL,88.188.114.14  etc, at present every time i select the state AL i always get the same value, and when i look in my database it is the first AL row it finds. I am really not sure what to add to make it not choose the first one and just randomly select one, any help would be great

Ali

Comment: @user1010914, thuis code works, you can test it in phpMyAdmin and see for yourself that it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem sometime back

You can use `NEWID()` rather than `RAND()` Function

```
SELECT *
FROM Northwind.Orders 
ORDER BY NEWID()
```